# Rollback in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

As far as I know, we can't use start transaction within functions, thus we can't use COMMIT and ROLLBACK in functions.

1. But how then we ROLLBACK by some if-condition?
2. How then we can perform a sequence of statements in a specific level of isolation? I mean a situation when an application wants to call a SQL (plpgsql) function and that function really needs to be run in a transaction with a certain isolation level. What to do in such a case?
3. In which cases then it is really practical to run ROLLBACK? Only when we manually write a script, check something and then ROLLBACK manually if we don't like the result. And in the same case, I see the practicality of savepoints. However, I feel like it is a serious constraint.

Comment: re 1) throw an error, re 2) the caller sets the isolation level

Comment: 2) I don't like that a SQL-developer can't do that in the end. It can only happen in a high-level application. Yes, we can call a function from a script setting an isolation level but who will run that script? I mean that mostly we call functions from high-level apps written in C# or Java (let's say) and I want to move the responsibility for isolation level management down to the db-level. It is obviously the responsibility of functions themselves to manage the isolation level of transactions.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to rollback the complete transaction, `RAISE` an exception.

   If you only want to roll back part of your work, start a new block with a `BEGIN` at the point to which you want to roll back and add an `EXCEPTION` clause to the block.
2. Since the transaction is started outside the function, the isolation level already has to be set properly when you are in the function.

   You can query

   ```
   SELECT current_setting('transaction_isolation', TRUE);
   ```

   and throw an error if the setting is not correct.
3. is too general or too simple to answer.

   You roll back a transaction if you have reached a point in your processing where you want to undo everything you have done so far in the transaction.

   Often, that happens implicitly rather than explicitly by throwing an error.

Comment: "Since the transaction is started outside the function". How is that? Who starts the transaction outside of the function with a specific isolation level? Do you mean that an application (written in say C#) starts it? In T-SQL, we can start a transaction within a procedure easily.

Comment: Yes, you can start a transaction in client code. But if you don't, PostgreSQL will automatically start one for you. The isolation level in that case is determined by the `default_transaction_isolation` parameter.

Comment: Don't you feel that it is odd to move the responsibility for isolation level management to the high-level application? Why an application should bother about low-level DB-related concepts? I feel like the approach in T-SQL is more logical in that sense. We write procedures managing the isolation level explicitly right where it needs to be done and a high-level application doesn't bother about such things. I understand that this is a bit philosophical but anyway I would be appreciate if you share your thoughts about that.

Comment: A function is something that is always run as part of an SQL statement. One SQL statement always runs withing one transaction (this has changed in PostgreSQL with the advent of the `CALL` statement). You may disagree with that concept, but it is a simple concept. Transactions are not particularly low-level. They specify what statements must always go together, and that is of course something that only the application logic can and shall control.

Comment: I suspect that we are actually talking about something different here: should application logic be written into database functions or not? You seem to be all for it, but obviously there can be different opinions. In the end it does not matter if the code is stored in the database or not.

Comment: Why didn't anyone mention that starting from postgres 11, we have stored procedures where we can manage the transactions explicitly?

Comment: I guess because the question explicitly asked about functions. Transaction support in procedures exists, but is limited (see [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-transactions.html), also, you cannot use it if the procedure runs in a multi-statement transaction).